# how to properly setup system.js

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I need some help about system.js module loader. I don't use it before so don't have any experience. Here I want to use Aurelia Framework to create a SPA web app. In my app code I import the framework module like below.

```
import { Aurelia } from "aurelia-framework";
```

After I import the module, I open a browser and navigate to my web app, then I see that system.js try to get javascript file with following url `localhost/aurelia-framework` but the correct url should be `localhost/node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/amd/aurelia-framework.js`.

I make some investigation from internet and see that I need to add a mapping to the systemjs configuration like below

```
System.config({
 map: {
  "aurelia-framework": "node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/amd/aurelia-framework.js",
 }
})
```

after above configuration, file is successfully requested by browser but now, all the dependencies of aurelia-framework failed to be downloaded, then I started to add all dependencies to the system.js mapping but it looks like there is no end for this because there are tons of dependencies, it looks very annoying to add all files to the mapping.

How are you handling module loading of these type apps?